# Log in redirect PHP

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

How can i log in and stay in the current page? With this structure whatever the page i'm visiting, when i log in, i always land on the home page: here's the code from the config, login and main.php files:

MGconfig file

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pwd = '';
$server = 'localhost';
$bdschema = 'MG';

// mysql(i) form improved
$connection = mysqli_connect($server,$user, $pwd, $bdschema);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Error to DB ..." .mysqli_error($connection);
    exit;
};

mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
//print_r($connection);


?>
```

Login.php (login file)

```
<?php

session_start();

$error="";
$successMessage="";

if ($_POST){
    if(!isset($_POST["salada"]) || $_POST["salada"]===""){
    $error = "PHP: An email is required <br>";
}


//If some field is missing, there's an error

if(!isset($_POST["arroz"]) || $_POST["arroz"]===""){
    $error .= "PHP: A password is required";
}

if ($error !=""){
    $error = '<div class="error-login">'.$error.'</div>';

    //try to do login

}else {

    //connect to DB
    require("MGconfig.php");

    //read parameters (fields)

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["salada"]);
    $pwd = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["arroz"]));

    //var_dump($email.$pwd);

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "select name, id from users where    email = '".$email."' and password = '".$pwd."'");

    //  alerta erro 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !==1){
        $error='<div class="error-login">PHP: Invalid email or password</div>';
        header("Location:index.php?error=".$error);

    }else {

            $nome = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

            $_SESSION["name"] = $nome[0];
            $_SESSION["id"]=$nome[1];

             header ("Location: main.php");
             }
           }


        }

        ?>
```

MAIN.PHP FILE

```
       <?php 
       session_start();
       ?>

       <?php 

        include "menu.php";


        if(isset($_GET["area"])){
        $destino = $_GET["area"];
        } else {
        $destino = "index";
        }

        switch($destino){

        case "formsubmit":{
            include("formsubmit.php");
            } break; 
        case "index": {
            include("inicio.php");
        } break;    

        case "videos": {
            include("videos.php");
        } break;

        case "FAQs": {
            include("FAQs.php");
        } break;

        case "quemsomos": {
            include("quemsomos.php");
        } break;

            case "form": {
            include("form.php");
        } break;                            

         default: {
            include("inicio.php");
        } break;

       }



       ?>
      </div>

      <div>

     <?php

     include "footer.php";

      ?>
     </div>
```

Comment: The easiest way ts to add a query parameter to the link that brings you to login page such as `<a href="/login?redirect=faq">Login</a>` and then use that query param for your Location header.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's not working - it says "Object not Found..." Im kind of new in PHP

Comment: After you change your login links - change `header ("Location: main.php");` to `header("Location: main.php?area=" . $_GET['redirect');`

Comment: I'm sorry, still not working...my form had a post metho, still it didnt worked...
The form: <a href="/login?redirect=index">Login</a>

The PHP: header("Location: main.php?area=" . $_POST['redirect'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott and MounirOnGithub: this worked(login file)

```
     header ("Location: main.php?area=".$_POST["area"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an `include('form.php');` in your main.php file.

Try to add the property action to your form like this :

```
<form action="your redirect">
    <!-- your code here -->
</form>
```

Comment: my current <form action> is the login file itself, so the program reads this file and this is where i have the header location (main.php)...and the main is where you find a switch with the areas specified...i dont get it

Comment: Maybe it's because you did `<a href="/login?redirect="index">Login</a>` I see it will redirect to `inicio.php`in your `main.php` as you said in your last comment

Comment: i've tried every possible combination based on your guys suggestions...I still get the 404 page...thanks anyaway, cheers